# Spring Cloud Open Feign: linebreaks "\n" stripped from gzip response body

Tags: spring, gzip, spring-cloud, openfeign

Linebreaks ("\n" or "\r") are been stripped out from **gzip** response body, when using response compression configuration (as below) in Spring Cloud Open Feign. There are no errors raised. Linebreaks are just been replace by an empty string "". The response has the correct "content-encoding: gzip" header, and a well formed gzipped body content.

Does someone has a clue? It seems a issue for me as I opened here [spring-cloud-openfeign/issue400](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/400)

```
feign.compression.response.enabled: true
feign.compression.response.useGzipDecoder: true

# Same behaviour using Apache Http as client
feign.httpclient.enabled: true
```

SpringCloudFeignClient.java

```
package springcloudfeigngzip;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@FeignClient(name = "SpringCloudFeignClient", url = "http://localhost:8082")
public interface SpringCloudFeignClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/gzip")
    String getGzippedString();     
}
```

ApplicationTest.java:

```
package springcloudfeigngzip;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8082)
class ApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private SpringCloudFeignClient springCloudFeignClient;

    @Test
    void success_GzipOneLine() {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/gzip")).withHeader("Accept-Encoding", containing("gzip"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200).withBody("lineone")));
    
        String response = springCloudFeignClient.getGzippedString();
        assertEquals("lineone", response); //success
    }

    @Test
    void fail_GzipLineBreak() {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/gzip")).withHeader("Accept-Encoding", containing("gzip"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200).withBody("lineone\nlinetwo")));
    
        String response = springCloudFeignClient.getGzippedString();
        assertEquals("lineone\nlinetwo", response); //fail!
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
feign:
  compression:
    response:
      enabled: true
      useGzipDecoder: true
```

Versions:

```
org.springframework.boot: 2.3.3.RELEASE
org.springframework.cloud: Hoxton.SR8
```

Full project here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/files/5147346/spring-cloud-feign-gzip.zip